# Schema for yearly data models

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema

I am developing a school management system.

Most data will not be reused after the end of the school year.

I am contemplating using schemas to separate data in various school years, however I am afraid I don't know very much about schemas.

Would it be a good idea to use a new schema for each school year to store data (see below), rather than adding a `year` field and using a `where` clause for all queries?

```
schema_year1.attendance_of_staff
schema_year2.attendance_of_staff
```

Comment: If you use a new schema for each school year, you will be faced with needing to recode your queries each time a new schema is created.

Comment: Cant we do it programmatic? @MaxVernon Thanks

Comment: "Most data will not be reused after the end of the school year", uh huh

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you should use **staff**, **attendance_staff**, and **school**.

```
staff table
==========
id, 
fullname,
birthday
...

school Table
==============
id,
name, 
founded,
number_of_staff
...

attendance_staff table
=======================
id,
staff_id,
school_id,
attended_date,
...
```